# How to Mysql INSERT into 2 tables at once where tableA has unique userID and tableB recurring userID

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the below queries which I'm iserting separately.

```
SQL1:
    INSERT INTO tableA (product) VALUES ('machine1'), ('machine2')

SQL2:
    INSERT INTO tableB (userid, name) VALUES (12345, 'Jan Smith'), (12345, 'Bert Smith'), (12346, 'Pieter King'), (12346, 'Martin King')
```

**tableA** has a unique primary key (autoincrement) on userID. **tableB** also has a column userID where userID is not unique.

Currently I use mysqli last inserted ID to obtain the first userID of the first inserted product from SQL1 which is machine1 in this case. In this case the number 12345 will be returned and will be used for SQL2.

I'm currently fetching the first userID and use it for the second SQL insertion while simply adding +1 for each next product assuming that the userID as given to the rows for SQL1 are all consecutive. As in the mean time there are already other insertions this approach is not valid and does not work. Further to that it is a dangeroes approach as the system breaks if any of the two SQL queries fail.

My question is: **"How can I combine the above two INSERTION queries into 1?"**

Comment: Would you mind giving the real names of tableA and tableB, it makes it easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html

INSERT INTO tbl (auto,text) VALUES(NULL,'text');
INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');

You can put both insert in the same transaction.

Comment: I need to insert multiple rows into table2 for the same ID, this approach seems not to be able to handle that.

Comment: What about storing the ID in a MySQL variable, i.e. SET @ tbl1_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); then use @ tble1_id. (cf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: I generated both queries in php and added (LAST_INSERT_ID()+ x) where is a number from 0 to the number of times an entry has to be added for each userid

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select the last inserted auto incremented id in MySQL by using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`; [Click here for DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

I haven't tested this but you are able to work this into your query as Nicolas showed in his example.

I see you are also inserting a name into the product purchase history, or something to that effect.
You should definitely be avoiding this. It would be better to only insert the user's ID and then set it as a foreign key to the user table.